# Adjunction map sends epimorphism to epimorphism

Tags: category-theory

My question is simple.

Let a functor $F : D \to C$ be a left adjoint to the functor $G: C \to D$. Let $X\in C$ , $Y \in D$. Therefore there is a natural bijection $\phi_{Y,X} : hom_{C}(F(Y),X) \to hom_{D}(Y,G(X))$ .

> If $f \in hom_{C}(F(Y),X)$ is an epimorphism, is
> $\phi_{Y,X}(f)$ also an epimorphism?

I have a motivation for this question which I will write later.
Anyway, can anyone help?

Comment: Surely this is incorrect in general, no? For an example the free functor $\mathbb Z[-]:Set\rightarrow Ab$ being the left adjoint to the forgetful functor, the identity in $Ab(\mathbb{Z}[S],\mathbb{Z}[S])$ is sent to the inclusion $S\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[S]$ under the adjunction map.

Comment: O.K. Uhm. very simple example. Thank you